# On the question regarding when the determinant's answer is going to be prime?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers, algebraic-number-theory

Let $a$ and $b$ are two consecutive prime numbers. 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
3 & b \\ 
2 & a 
\end{vmatrix}$$
Gauss's Prime number theorem is the best object to study about prime numbers between any two natural numbers. But this theorem can also be used to have a matrix whose determinant is always a prime number.
Let $p$ be any prime number,
Using Prime number theorem we have,
$$f(x) ={ x \over \ln(x)}$$
Now, 
$$\pi(p-1) - \pi(3) = A$$
Here, A = even number.
Now, determinant is as follows:
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 - p \\ 
3 & A  & 2\\ 
p & -3  & p-1
\end{vmatrix} \pm 1$$
The value of above Determinant is always a prime number.

I have doubt that most probably, my logic in the 3x3 determinant is true, but in 2x2 determinant, I want to know that if a and b are two consecutive primes **when the answer of 2x2 and 3x3 determinant will be a prime**?

Comment: Do you have a proof or reference why this expression is always prime ? Additionaly, $f(p-1)-f(3)$ is not an integer.  So, how is $A$ actually defined ?

Comment: @Peter it’s simply the representation for number of primes between p-1 and 3. I don’t have any proof for it and that’s why I have posted it as my doubt which I have mentioned in last line.

Comment: @AzizLokhandwala We usually use 2D and 3D to denote  two dimensional and three  dimensional. There are three dimensional matrices, but yours is not one of them.

Comment: You seem to think that the number of primes less than $x$ is given by $\frac x{\log x}$.  This is not true.  This number is not even an integer.

Comment: @saulspatz prime number theorem gives you an approximation of number of primes less than x

Comment: I think people will be happier if you use the notation $\pi(x)$ for the number of primes $\le x$ and write $\pi(x) \sim x/\log x$ instead of $\pi(x) = x/\log x$.

Comment: Yes it does give an approximation, so it's useless in determining whether a number is prime.

Comment: @saulspatz changed it

Comment: @saulspatz my question is when is it going to be prime!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's consider the determinant 
$$\begin{vmatrix}
3 & b \\ 
2 & a 
\end{vmatrix}$$

Which is actually $3a-2b$ and it's not well controlled especially when our demand is of output which should be prime number.

But I have something which might interest you in some way.

Once upon a time I Conjectured that $3p_n + 2p_{n-1}$ is either prime or semiprime, but it's validity was transient. But for sure it does take Infinitude of primes. Note that $p_n$ is the $nth$ prime.

---

I'll assume that you meant exact count of primes, not asymptotically.

Let's define $T(x)$ to be the exact count of prime numbers below any given number $x$

Now considering your following determinant
$$\begin{vmatrix}
2 & -1 & 3 - p \\ 
3 & A  & 2\\ 
p & -3  & p-1
\end{vmatrix} \pm 1$$

Where $A$ is meant to be an positive even integer such that $T(p-1) - T(3) = A$

Your claim is such that the value of determinant is always a prime.

The determinant boils down to 
$Ap^2 + p(A+10) -1(30+2A) \pm1$

By solving the above Quadratic in any prime $p$ we can obtain the values of $p$ which are admissible.

For negative case, which is 
$Ap^2 + p(A+10) -(31+2A)$ we can easily prove that there doesn't exist any such prime $p$, while assuming everything same as you mentioned.

**Counterexample**
Consider $p=19$ we have $T(19-1) - 1 = A = 6$

Plug in $p=19$ and $A=6$ in 
$Ap^2 + p(A+10) -1(30+2A) \pm1$ we get $2428 \pm1$ which yields $2427$ and $2429$ none of them are primes.

Comment: T(18)-T(3) = Number of primes between 18 and 3 and it is equal to 5 in this case which is not a even number.